# Мониторинг пинга сервера

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать маленький tool для мониторинга статуса сервера своего.

Для мониторинга IP и URL.

Что бы выводить пинг его...

Примерно вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто не знаю как написать такой код.

Comment: Можно через Process.Start запустить консоль, предварительно перенаправив поток вывода в вашу программу.

Comment: Ну еще есть класс https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код.

Совет: выполняйте в отдельном потоке.

```cs
 using (Ping ping = new Ping())
 {
   PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("ВАШ IP"); 

   if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) //Пингуетесь к серваку, если статус OK- он работает
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Статус: "+pingReply.Status);
    Console.WriteLine(pingReply.RoundtripTime + " мс");
   }
    else
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Статус: "+pingReply.Status);
         Console.WriteLine(pingReply.RoundtripTime + " мс");

        }
 }
```

Comment: Выдает множество ошибок. https://imgur.com/a/6Z111tx

Comment: @Zekoy так вы выводите в лейблы которых у вас нет

Comment: @Zekoy обновил воспользуйтесь.

Comment: Да, всё работает, но по моему остается одно и тоже значение, не обновляется значение, поставил рядом два окна - в cmd значения изменяются, а в консоли - нет.

Comment: @Zekoy я и говорю выполните в бесконечном потоке с задержкой в 1 мс